# Publishing to a page using Facebook for Wordpress plugin

Tags: facebook, wordpress

**Short question**: Does a page owner need to be logged in to Facebook for the Wordpress plugin to publish to a page?

**Detailed question**:

I am trying to configure the [Facebook for Wordpress plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/wordpress/) so that it will automatically post things that are published in Wordpress to a specified Facebook page.  I was able to make this work initially by using the `Social Publisher` setting when I was logged in to Facebook.

However, when one of the other authors using the Wordpress site tried to publish a story he received an authentication error from the Facebook plugin.  I am trying to understand how the authentication for a page works and whether every user that wants to publish to a page needs to have permission to do so and to be logged in to Facebook while using Wordpress.  Or is there a way to authorize the Facebook app that is associated with the Wordpress plugin to publish to a page even if no one is logged in to Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a page access token as described here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/ Your app can post to your page using it, no matter who is the actual user who triggers your app’s actions.

Make sure you get yourself a [long-lived](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) user access token first – that way you’ll get a page access token that will have no default expiry. (Also it will expire f.i. if the user you used to get it with changes their Facebook password.)

Comment: The page you are linking to seems to provide details for someone writing their own code to do this. It doesn't make any sense how to use this w/ the Facebook for Wordpress plugin. Am I missing something?